# Fetch all the users assigned to a planner task via Graph API

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

how do I fetch all the users assigned to a planner task using graph API. The result doesn't show the list of users if I use the below query:

````
var tasks = await GraphClient.Planner.Buckets[BucketId].Tasks
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();```
````

Comment: The code talks about the list of plannerTasks in a bucket.  Do you want the users assigned to a particular task or you just want the list tasks in the bucket?

Comment: You can use [Assignemnts property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) to get the ID's of users that are assigned to a task.

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: Hi, moving this to answer, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The code of ours talks about the list of plannerTasks in a bucket.You can use [Assignemnts property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) to get the ID's of users that are assigned to a task.

Comment: tired but no luck.. anyways building a custom module for the same. thanks!